# Gnome 3 Effects

Tags: linux, gnome3

Gnome3 lacks in windows effects since it does not use compiz as window manager.

My question is if is there something i can do to have some effects back? (e.g aero effect like in win7, avaliable in ccsm)

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 Natty w/ Gnome3 in fallback mode.

Comment: Would you like the obvious solution?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I'm listening...